# Python, Algoritmo de Warshall

Tags: python, c++, teoría-de-grafos

Buen día a todos como están? he intentado replicar el algoritmo de Warshall en python, pero no me funciona, en clase lo hicimos en C++ y todo va bien, pero en python no he podido lograr que funcione, que estoy haciendo mal?

Scritp en Python

```
print("Programa que usa el algoritmo de warshall para hacer el cierre 
transitivo de una relacion")
print()
v=int(input("Introduce la cantida de vertices de tu grafo: "));
print()
#ahora lo que vamos a hacer es por defecto pedir los valores de la matriz 
para poder ejecutarla.
Ma1=[]#declaramos la matriz para poder usarla mas adelante
Ma2=[]# la seguna matriz que me da el volumen
for i in range(v):
   Ma1.append([])

#ACA YA CREE LA MATRIZ NECESARIA PARA PODER TRABAJAR
va1=0
for i in range(v):
    var2=i+1
    for j in range(v):
        var3=j+1
        print("Introduce el valor ",var3," para la fila ",var2," a 
        continuacion")
    va1=int(input(":"))
    Ma1[j].append(va1)
for i in range (v):
    print(Ma1[i])
    print()

for k in range(v):
    for i in range(v):
        for j in range (v):
            Ma1[i][j]=Ma1[i][j] or (Ma1[i][k] and Ma1[k][j])#para acceder o 
            hacer slicing es necesario porner los dos corchetes
 print("El resultado del cierre transitivo es el siguiente: ")
 print()
 for i in range(v):
     print(Ma1[i])
     print()
```

acá les dejo el algoritmo formulado en C++

```
#include <stdio.h> 

 int main(){ 
int M[4][4]={{0, 0, 0, 1},{1, 0, 1, 0},{1, 0, 0, 1},{0, 0, 1, 0}};
/* Aca empieza el algoritmo de Marshall*/
for (int k=0; k<4; k++){
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            M[i][j]= M[i][j] || M[i][k] && M[k][j]; 
        }
    }

        for (int m=0; m<4; m++){ 
        for (int n=0; n<4; n++){
        printf("%d ", M[m][n]);

    }
    printf ("\n");    
}
printf ("\n");
}


return 0;
}
```

En el algoritmo en C++ no  introducimos los valores por terminal si no que se introducen dentro del código, en el código de python cree las variables necesarias para poder darle  mas control al usuario, les ofrezco disculpas por la precariedad del código, apenas estoy aprendiendo Python y todavía no me quiero aventurar con C++.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no funciona? Qué datos usas para probar el código en C++ y en Python? Qué sale en uno y qué sale en otro? Te sale algún mensaje de error? Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye esta información para que todos puedan ayudarte más rápido y fácil.

Comment: Revisa la indentación del código python que has puesto en la pregunta a ver si es exactamente así como lo tienes, pues en ese caso estaría mal. Pero puede deberse a un error al copiar y pegar en Stack Overflow. Para asegurarte de que no es lo segundo, la forma más sencilla de marcar el código es precederlo de una línea con triple backtick ``` , pegarlo sin más (sin pulsar el botón {}, que le añadiría espacios por delante) y cerrar con una línea de triple backtick ```

Comment: No, ya no, creo que encontré que el problema es que estoy ubicando mal los elementos en las listas

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo pude solucionar, era un problema de como iba agregando los valores en la lista, les dejo el scritp para quien lo quiera usar mas adelante, feliz día.

```
print("Programa que usa el algoritmo de warshall para hacer el cierre transitivo de 
una relacion")
print()
v=int(input("Introduce la cantida de vertices de tu grafo: "));
print()
#ahora lo que vamos a hacer es por defecto pedir los valores de la matriz para poder 
ejecutarla.
Ma1=[]#declaramos la matriz para poder usarla mas adelante
Ma2=[]# la seguna matriz que me da el volumen
for i in range(v):
    Ma1.append([])

#ACA YA CREE LA MATRIZ NECESARIA PARA PODER TRABAJAR
var1=0
var2=0
count1=0
a=0
while a<4:
    var1=var1+1
    for i in range(v):
        var2=i+1
        print("Fila ",var1)
        print("Introduce el numero de la columna ", var2)
        b=int(input(": "))
        Ma1[count1].append(b)
    a=a+1
    count1=count1+1



for k in range(v):
    for i in range(v):
        for j in range (v):
        Ma1[i][j]=Ma1[i][j] or (Ma1[i][k] and Ma1[k][j])#para acceder o hacer slicing 
es necesario porner los dos corchetes
print("El resultado del cierre transitivo es el siguiente: ")
print()
for i in range(v):
    print(Ma1[i])
     print()
```